# can't install GIMP Flatpak

Tags: gnome, software-installation, gimp, flatpak

I'm reading GIMP's Flatpak documentation [here](https://www.gimp.org/downloads/). I go ahead and issue the following command after installing Flatpak on my Ubuntu 18.04 system

```
flatpak install --user https://flathub.org/repo/appstream/org.gimp.GIMP.flatpakref
```

and I get the following error

```
error: The Application org.gimp.GIMP/x86_64/stable requires the org.gnome.Platform/x86_64/3.28 which was not found
```

What went wrong? Why does it tell me I don't have the GNOME platform. I'm using *Bionic Beaver* which by default uses GNOME.

Comment: I think it is saying that you haven't version 3.28; not that you haven't Gnome.

Comment: If you use 18.04, install Gimp from the repos or from the [Gimp PPA](https://launchpad.net/~otto-kesselgulasch/+archive/ubuntu/gimp) if you want the latest and greatest. The flatpak version is not well integrated with the system and is only tolerable as a stopgap measure for those running pre-17.10 Ubuntu releases.

Comment: Install it from snap: `sudo snap install gimp`